# Incoming shortwave radiation for SEBAL in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to create incoming shortwave radiation for SEBAL model in GEE. Unfortunately, the error occurs: <quote Image.select: Pattern 'EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE' did not match any bands. >quote

```
var  filtered = landsattoa.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')
                       .filterBounds(uae)
                       .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
var dem = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').clip(uae);
var elevation = dem.select('elevation');
Map.addLayer(elevation, {min: 0, max: 60}, 'elevation');


function addRinc(image) {
  
  var transmissivity = ee.Image.constant(0.75).multiply(2).multiply(0.00001).multiply(elevation);
  var rinc = (transmissivity.multiply(1367).multiply(image.select('EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE')).multiply(ee.Number(image.select('SUN_ELEVATION')).cos())).rename('R_incoming_shortwave');

  return image.addBands(rinc);
  
}

var filtered = filtered.map(addRinc);
Map.addLayer(filtered.select('R_incoming_shortwave'), imageVisParam, 'R incoming shortwave');
```

Comment: Your image collection **filtered** doesn't have 'EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE' band.

Comment: why? in metadata profile it said it has

Comment: i use ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is produced because you're assuming that 'EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE' and 'SUN_ELEVATION' are bands in filtered collection and this is not true. They are properties and the method for retrieving them is .get. On the other hand, you are not putting the formula for determining **rinc** so, I am assuming that your arithmetic operations are corrects. As 'SUN_ELEVATION' is expressed in degrees, you also should corroborate if cosine function requires radians instead degrees.

So, I modified your code as follows; where **uae** is an arbitrary area in image zone.

```
var uae = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[57.36213307516186, 26.493020474959547],
          [57.36213307516186, 26.14836450809302],
          [57.80158620016186, 26.14836450809302],
          [57.80158620016186, 26.493020474959547]]], null, false);

var landsattoa = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA");

var  filtered = landsattoa.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')
                       .filterBounds(uae)
                       .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10));
                       
print(filtered);

var test = filtered.first();

print("EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE", test.get('EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE'));
print("SUN_ELEVATION", test.get('SUN_ELEVATION'));

var dem = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4').clip(uae);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["elevation"],
                     "min":54,
                     "max":1508,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.centerObject(uae);
Map.addLayer(uae);
Map.addLayer(dem, imageVisParam, 'dem');

function addRinc(image) {
  
  var transmissivity = ee.Image.constant(0.75)
                               .multiply(2)
                               .multiply(0.00001)
                               .multiply(dem);
  
  var earth_sun_distance = image.get('EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE');
  var sun_elevation = image.get('SUN_ELEVATION');
  
  var rinc = transmissivity.multiply(1367)
                           .multiply(ee.Number(earth_sun_distance)
                           .multiply(ee.Number(sun_elevation)
                           .cos()))
                           .toFloat()
                           .rename('R_incoming_shortwave');

  return image.addBands(rinc);
  
}

var filtered = filtered.map(addRinc);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["R_incoming_shortwave"],
                     "min":-5.9374,
                     "max":2.7116,
                     "palette":["fbff0e","ff9b04","ff3f06","1224ff"]};

Map.addLayer(filtered.select('R_incoming_shortwave'), imageVisParam, 'R incoming shortwave');
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, it was obtained result of following picture for 'R_incoming_shortwave' image.

[image]